# vCPU limit of all instances containing GPU is 0

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to launch some instances that contain GPU (p2,p3,g3 or g4) in AWS EC2 but found that all the vCPU limits of these instances are 0. I requested to extend the vCPU limits but was rejected twice by AWS. They told me that I need to use my current instance capacity first. Now I am confused, I think in my case there is no instance capacity I can use now if I want to use GPU resources. Does that mean for an AWS new user, we cannot use GPU resources at the beginning? Do I misunderstand something, or maybe there are some other things I need to do first? (My codes require GPU so there is meaningless for me to use CPUs in AWS)
Thanks!

Comment: I think asking at https://old.reddit.com/r/aws/ is better for aws support level questions.